# How to check a field contains in jsonb array in postgres

Tags: postgresql

My table contains a column called "actions" which is of `jsonb` type:

```
CREATE TABLE wealth_rule (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- '自增id',
    actions jsonb, -- 对应的路由，数组
    ...
);
```

the "actions" column contains data like:

```
["/qa/favorite", "/user/update"]
```

now I have to check which row contains action 'user/update'

what can I do to find the row?

Answer (score 0):

You should test for [containment](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-CONTAINMENT) on the `jsonb` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM wealth_rule
WHERE actions @> '["/user/update"]'::jsonb;
```